# web.config 404 error URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, http-status-code-404

I have an e-commerce site where after changing the URL structure, I am losing out on a lot of traffic from links submitted at various platforms. I have 2 questions:

1. I would like to know how to rewrite the URL from example.com/asdasd to the custom example.com/404 page where **example.com/asdasd does not exist**, using the web.config file or if there is any other way to rewrite the URL.
2. If there is a page example.com/asdasd**.aspx(with extension)** from my older URL structure, the page does not redirect to the custom 404 page at all.

EDIT ---

Simply put, what I was trying to say was that the custom 404 page is not displayed when a non existing page with an *.aspx extension is hit.

Also when example.com/asdasd is loaded, the URL stays /asdasd and does not rewrite to /404

Comment: The questions are a bit confusing. Generally, 404 should be hit whenever a page doesn't exist, unless you are using rounting in your code, regardless whether it's with or without extension. Looks like you have another problem.

Comment: Simply put, what I was trying to say was that the **custom 404 page is not displayed when a non existing page with an *.aspx extension is hit.**

Also when example.com/asdasd is loaded, the URL stays /asdasd and does not rewrite to /404

Comment: Please show your web.config. Are there any rewrite rules defined? And it the error page setting correct?